# Calling function inside javascript class functions?

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to declare properties and functions to a specific js class. But when I try to call function inside a function (even if called after declared) it throws a exception

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addButtonEventListeners

My code listed: SplashScene.js

```
var anim1, background;
var SplashScene;

function SplashScreen(SceneContainer)
{
this.name = "SplashScreen";
this.loadScreen = function()
{

    background = new createjs.Shape();
    background.graphics.beginBitmapFill(loader.getResult("gameLoopSplash")).drawRect(0,0,w,h);
    SplashScene = new createjs.Container();

    anim1 = new createjs.Sprite(buttonData, "playIdle");
    anim1.framerate = 30;
    anim1.x = 260;
    anim1.y = 22;
    SplashScene.alpha = 0;

    SplashScene.addChild(background);
    SplashScene.addChild(anim1);
}

this.addButtonEventListeners =  function()
{
    console.log("addButtonEventListeners   SplashScreen" );
}

this.menuIn = function()
{
    console.log("menuIn   SplashScreen" );
    stage.addChild(SplashScene);
    var tween = createjs.Tween.get(SplashScene).to({y : 0, x : 0, alpha : 1}, 5000).call(this.menuInCompleted);
    var splashTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){menuOut("MainScreen", false)},15000);

}

this.menuInCompleted = function()
{
    console.log("menuInCompleted   SplashScreen" );
    this.addButtonEventListeners();
}
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the context (`this`) in the `setTimeout` callback is `window`, not your object.

You can change

```
var splashTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){menuOut("MainScreen", false)},15000);
```

to

```
var splashTimer = window.setTimeout(
     (function(){menuOut("MainScreen", false)}).bind(this)
,15000);
```

and you also have to do the same where you bind `menuIn` (to an event?).

Comment: the menu in tween is working but menu out not. I did what you said. But  it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `this`, which points to the current context (in runtime) and not to your object's one.
Just add a variable in SplashScreen like:

```
var self=this; //keeping the context of SplashScreen
```

And then call it as follows:

```
this.menuInCompleted = function()
{
    console.log("menuInCompleted   SplashScreen" );
    self.addButtonEventListeners ();
}
```